# How to change the font?

Tags: openoffice-impress, libreoffice-impress, libreoffice-macros

I want to change the font and set its style to bold.
I have two problems:

- changing `CharWeight` works but not `CharFontName`
- it applies "bold" to the whole paragraph, not only to the selection

Here's my code:

```
sub AddAnimation
    xTextCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Selection(0)
    xText = xTextCursor.getText()
    xText.CharFontName = "Consolas"
    xText.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
end Sub
```

Comment: What is the font name currently set to?  Try starting with an empty document and creating one text block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `getText()` gets the entire text, not just the selected part.

```vb
Sub ChangeFont
    xTextCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Selection(0)
    xTextCursor.CharFontName = "Consolas"
    xTextCursor.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
End Sub
```

The font name changed when I tried it, using both LO and AOO.

[image: result]

Are you using [CTL or CJK](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Languages#Asian) scripts?  If so, then it needs to be `CharFontNameComplex` or `CharFontNameAsian`.  However if `CharWeight` worked, then that must not be the issue.

One more guess: Maybe a style is overriding it.

Comment: How to change the style then?

Comment: Go to "Styles and Formatting" in the sidebar to see if that is the problem.  Apparently the relevant styles are called [Graphic Styles](https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Styles_and_Formatting#Graphic_Styles).

Comment: Such a mess in the source code, I've given up on this, thanks for your answer!